# Prove there exists a $2$-coloring of the points of the projective plane of order $11$ such that every line has at least two points of each color

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, coloring

To clarify, the projective plane of order $11$ has $133$ lines and $133$ points; any two lines intersect in one point, and any two points determine one line; there are exactly $12$ points on each line, and each point lies on exactly $12$ lines.

I've been thinking about the above problem for a while now, and I believe that I need to use pigeonhole principle. However, I'm not sure how to use pigeonhole principle to prove the existence of a special coloring rather than a guaranteed property of any coloring.

I've also looked at the smaller case of the projective plane of order $3$**, and it seems that this plane has no $2$-coloring such that each line has at least $1$ point of each color. If that's true, I'm not sure how to prove it, although I believe that the strategy to prove this case could help me solve the original problem.

I would appreciate any help, especially a hint or approach that I can use to find the rest of the solution on my own!

EDIT*: I sketched a potential solution in the comments below; please feel free to critique it!

EDIT**: I meant order $2,$ with $7$ points and $7$ lines. Sorry about the confusion there!

Comment: Nice question.  Do you have reason to believe that such a two-coloring exists?

Comment: Question:  Is it known that there's a unique projective plane of order $11$?  If so, then perhaps the construction of the plane will motivate a $2$-coloring.

Comment: @saulspatz This question is from an archived class that I'm working through (http://www-math.mit.edu/~goemans/18310S15/18310A.html), so hopefully the instructor wasn't sneaky enough to assign a false theorem to prove!

Comment: @Aqua The projective plane of order 11 and the complete graph with 133 vertices aren't the same object, since in $K_{133}$, each point lies on 132 lines.

Comment: @RobertShore I believe that the projective plane is unique in the sense that we have strict conditions that the points and lines of the projective plane must satisfy. A construction seems difficult, as there are 133 vertices and lines, and unnecessary, as we aren't expected to have prior knowledge of projective planes

Comment: I did an exhaustive computer search for an admissible two-coloring of the projective plane of order $3$ and came up empty.  Since each line must have $2$ points of each color, there's probably a way to prove non-existence without brute force.

Comment: @JuliusTao I haven't been able to find out if the uniqueness of the plane of order $11$ has been settled.  This isn't a simple matter.  Look at the beginning of [this paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1956-10-056/S0025-5718-1956-0084142-0/S0025-5718-1956-0084142-0.pdf)

Comment: I hope I'm not giving a false sense of hope, but here's a possible solution I thought of:

Let $X$ be the discrete random variable that counts the number of lines that have at least 2 points of each color. Let $X_i$ be the indicator variable for line $i$. Then $E(X) = E(\sum_{i=1}^{133} X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{133} E(X_i) = 133 (1 - \frac{26}{2^{12}}) = 133 - \frac{1729}{2048} > 132.$ There exists a 1-coloring where $X = 0$, but $E(X) > 132$, so there must exist a 2-coloring where $X = 133$. Therefore, there exists a 2-coloring such that all 133 lines each have at least 2 points of each color.

Comment: @bof Good question! We agree that there are 2 lines that are monochromatic. However, we also have to subtract out the 24 lines that have 11 points of one color and 1 point of the other, as the original question asks for a 2-coloring where each line has at least 2 points of each color.

Comment: @saulspatz If you $2$-color the $13$ points of a projective plane of order $3$, there will be at least $7$ points of one color. If no $3$ of those points were collinear, then they would determine $\binom72=21$ lines which is absurd.

Comment: For the projective plane of order $3$, I showed in my last comment that you can't $2$-color the points so that each line has two points of each color. As for the projective plane of order $2$, you can't even $2$-color the points so that each line has at least one point of each color.

Comment: Suppose the points of the projective plane of order $2$ are colored red and blue. We may assume there are at most $3$ red points. If, say, there are just $2$ red points, then the number of lines containing a red point is $3+3-1=5$ by the in-and-out formula, so there are two lines with only blue points. Now suppose there are just $3$ red points, and they are noncollinear; then the number of lines containing a red point is $3+3+3-1-1-1+0=6$, so there is one line with only blue points.

Answer (score 5):

Reposted from the comments for more visibility:

Let $X$ be the discrete random variable that counts the number of lines that have at least 2 points of each color. Let $X_i$ be the indicator variable for line $i$.

Then $\mathbb{E}(X) = \mathbb{E}(\sum_{i=1}^{133} X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{133} \mathbb{E}(X_i) = 133(1−\frac{26}{2^{12}}) = 133 − \frac{1729}{2048} > 132.$ There exists a 1-coloring where $X=0$, but $\mathbb{E}(X) > 132$, so there must exist a 2-coloring where $X=133$. Therefore, there exists a 2-coloring such that all 133 lines each have at least 2 points of each color.

Answer (score 2):

Choose four lines, no three of which are concurrent. Call these the *chosen* lines, and call the other 129 lines *ordinary* lines.

Provisionally, color a point red if it lies on exactly one chosen line, blue otherwise. (Some colors will be changed later.)

Each chosen line has $9$ red points and $3$ blue points.

Each ordinary line has at least $8$ blue points.

*Most* ordinary lines have at least $2$ red points. The exceptions are lines which pass through two points, each of which is the intersection of two chosen lines. There are $3$ such lines. On each of those $3$ exceptional lines, choose two points which lie on no chosen line, and recolor them red.

In the revised coloring, every line has at least $2$ red points. The chosen lines are unaffected, as the recolored points do not lie on any chosen line. And since each ordinary line had at least $8$ blue points to start with, and at most $6$ points have been recolored, each ordinary line still has at least $2$ blue points.

**P.S.** This construction actually achieves a slightly better result: every line has at least $2$ red points and at least $3$ blue points. This is because the $6$ recolored points can't all be collinear, so no line loses too many blue points in the recoloring. In fact, we don't have to recolor more than $4$ points: if the $3$ exceptional lines are concurrent, recolor the point of concurrency and one more point on each of the $3$ lines; otherwise just recolor the $3$ points where the exceptional lines intersect in pairs.