# Does every two-set partition of a projective plane contain a line?

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry, finite-geometry

Define a two-set partition of a projective plane as a partition of the points into two sets. Does there exist for any two-set partition a set in the partition that contains a line? What about infinite projective planes?

Comment: What does it mean for your "two-sat partitition" to "contain a line"? The elements of the partition are not lines, they are sets of points. And *every* point belongs to one of the two sets. Did you mean to ask, does one of the two sets necessarily contain a line? If that's your question the answer is no, though it's true for the projective plane of order $2$. The answers to the following question are a great overkill: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3718453/prove-there-exists-a-2-coloring-of-the-points-of-the-projective-plane-of-order-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every projective plane of order at least $3$ (i.e. at least $4$ points on a line) admits a "$2$-set partition" in which neither set contains a line. In other words, we can color each point red or blue so that every line contains at least one point of each color. (As you probably know, the projective plane of order $2$ does not admit such a partition.)

**Proof.** Choose three non-concurrent lines $\ell_1$, $\ell_2$, and $\ell_3$. Color a point red if it lies on exactly one of those three lines, blue otherwese.

I claim that every line contains points of both colors. This is plainly true for the lines $\ell_1$, $\ell_2$, and $\ell_3$, so consider a line $\ell\notin\{\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3\}$. Then $\ell$ must contain a red point, since it can't intersect all three of the lines $\ell_1$, $\ell_2$, $\ell_3$ in blue points. On the other hand, since every red point lies on $\ell_1$ or $\ell_2$ or $\ell_3$, and since $\ell$ intersects each of those three lines in just one point, there are at most $3$ red points on $\ell$, so there is at least one blue point on $\ell$.